# iOS PresentViewController with Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyboard, presentviewcontroller

I'm actually struggling with the keyboard ! I have a viewController that I present like this :

```
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In this viewController, I have a textfield which becomeFirstResponder like this :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

The thing is that when the view appear, the keyboard just pop. It is not smooth at all. I would like to make it exactly like in the native iOS app Message : When you click on compose a message (top right corner). It **presents** a new **viewController** with the **keyboard**, all **animated**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say the keyboard just pops you mean it doesn't animate in at all? It just appears?

Comment: @slickdaddy yes exactly ! no animation, just a blink

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `becomeFirstResponder()` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: There is additional information needed than what is provided in the code sample above if this does not work. Presenting a view controller with a text field from a clean project in this manner animates how you'd expect. If you're testing via the simulator try a physical device, I've had trouble with the keyboard and the simulator in the past.

Comment: here is the code where I call the presentViewController method :

    `@objc private func addButtonAction() {

        let vc = viewController()
let navigationController = navigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }`

Comment: And I tried to compile it on my phone, the problem is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Move it to viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```